# Is it valid to use std::transform with std::back_inserter?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, c++17

Cppreference has this example code for [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::vector<std::size_t> ordinals;
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(ordinals),
               [](unsigned char c) -> std::size_t { return c; });
```

But it also says:

> `std::transform` does not guarantee in-order application of `unary_op` or `binary_op`. To apply a function to a sequence in-order or to apply a function that modifies the elements of a sequence, use `std::for_each`.

This is presumably to allow parallel implementations. However the third parameter of `std::transform` is a [`LegacyOutputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) which has the following postcondition for `++r`:

> After this operation `r` is not required to be incrementable and any copies of the previous value of `r` are no longer required to be dereferenceable or incrementable.

So it seems to me that the assignment of the output *must* happen in order. Do they simply mean that the application of `unary_op` may be out of order, and stored to a temporary location, but copied to the output in order? That doesn't sound like something you'd ever want to do.

Most C++ libraries haven't actually implemented parallel executors yet, but Microsoft has. I'm pretty sure [this](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/da0d8cfdef750abd55e1874b81252b99934c1329/stl/inc/execution#L2336) is the relevant code, and I *think* it calls [this `populate()` function](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/da0d8cfdef750abd55e1874b81252b99934c1329/stl/inc/execution#L869) to record iterators to chunks of the output, which surely isn't a valid thing to do because  `LegacyOutputIterator` can be invalidated by incrementing copies of it.

What am I missing?

Comment: A simple test in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4WEUat) shows this is an issue. With C++20 and `transform` version which decides whether or not to use paralelism. The `transform` for large vectors fails.

Comment: @Croolman Your code is incorrect, since you are back-inserting back to `s`, which invalidates iterators.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica Oh schnitzel you're right. Was tweaking it and left it in non-valid state. I take my comment back.

Comment: If you use `std::transform` with exaction policy then [random access iterator is required](https://godbolt.org/z/f97Y4N) which `back_inserter` can't fulfill. IMO quoted part documentation refers to that scenario. Note example in documentation uses `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: @Croolman Decides to use parallelism automatically?

Comment: @Croolman, I don't think paralellism is the problem. When choosing `std::execution::par` explicitly the code doesn't compile so it is hard to think that it is automatically choosing to run in parallel. https://godbolt.org/z/Ys3hrd . Also I am not expert in assembly code, but the generated code doesn't seem to be calling threads, is it?

Comment: @DanielLangr, Croolman code is the same as in the OP question. Are you saying that the cppreference code (still there) is incorrect because pointer invalidation?

Comment: @alfC I need to admit that I am confused about my comment after such a long time. I don't understand why I wrote about "back-inserting back to `s`", when that back-inserting is actually to `ordinals`. I even can't find any edit that would explain this. I could overlooked myself, of course, but why would I get 6 upvotes without any notification about my mistake?

Comment: @DanielLangr, don't worry. I am trying to understand as well. (I left comments in the answer). I can ask the same question about the code in cppreference.com (same as OP's and Croolman), cppreference is reviewed by (more than 6) experts all the time and the use of `std::transform` with`std::back_insert_iterator` is still there.

Comment: How does it happen that someone flashbacks to old questions? Anyway @DanielLangr my code on first comment is wrong and that is what you have pointed out. When you change the `back_inserter` to inset to `ordinals` in `godbolt` it compiles and seems to work.

Comment: @Croolman . Questions transcend time. what is the “change back_inserted to inset (sic)” that you are referring to?   Btw. I went back and forth on this question and I think the answer is that the use is valid because backinserter or any specialization is always output iterators and that requires in-order iteration.

Comment: @alfC The `godbolt` code has an issue, that in the `std::back_inserter` the `s` is passed in, instead of `ordinals`

Comment: @Croolman ah, got it. So, it is in effect completely unrelated to question. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @alfC  Precisely

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) The output iterator requirements in the standard are completely broken. See [LWG2035](https://wg21.link/LWG2035).

2) If you use a purely output iterator and a purely input source range, then there's little else the algorithm can do in practice; it has no choice but to write in order. (However, a hypothetical implementation can choose to special-case its own types, like `std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<size_t>>`; I don't see why any implementation would want to do it here, but it is permitted to do so.)

3) Nothing in the standard guarantees that `transform` applies the transformations in-order. We are looking at an implementation detail.

That `std::transform` requires only output iterators does not mean it cannot detect higher iterator strengths and reorder the operations in such cases. Indeed, algorithms dispatch on iterator strength *all the time*, and they have special handling for special iterator types (like pointers or vector iterators) *all the time*.

When the standard wants to guarantee a particular order, it knows how to say it (see `std::copy`'s "starting from `first` and proceeding to `last`").

Comment: I find quite surprising that std::copy is not implementable as a special case of std::transform.

Comment: I don't understand you point about specializing `std::back_insert_iterator`. Are you saying that such case might be implemented with `operator+=`? making it effectively random access? And therefore allowing `std::transform` to do the operation out of order. It would be pretty crazy, but I can't pin point why. I think it would be because output iterator has undefined behavior if `++` and `*` are not applied interleaved. That alone should prevent even trying to implement `+=` (and having the semantics of applying `++` many times).

Comment: I think the "interleaved" requirement is spelled in the phrases: "After this operation (`*`) r is not required to be dereferenceable and any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required to be dereferenceable or incrementable. " and "After this operation (`++`) r is not required to be incrementable and any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required to be dereferenceable or incrementable. ". Here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator. I think this makes impossible a different out of order implementation and specialization of `back_insert_iterator`.

Answer (score 7):

From [`n4385`](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4835.pdf):

§25.6.4 **Transform**:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation>
constexpr OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1, OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op);

template<class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class UnaryOperation>
ForwardIterator2
transform(ExecutionPolicy&& exec, ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1, ForwardIterator2 result, UnaryOperation op);

template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator, class BinaryOperation>
constexpr OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1, InputIterator2 first2, OutputIterator result, BinaryOperation binary_op);

template<class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class ForwardIterator, class BinaryOperation>
ForwardIterator
transform(ExecutionPolicy&& exec, ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1, ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator result, BinaryOperation binary_op);
```

§23.5.2.1.2 **back_inserter**

```
template<class Container>
constexpr back_insert_iterator<Container> back_inserter(Container& x);
```

> Returns: back_insert_iterator(x).

§23.5.2.1 **Class template back_insert_iterator**

```
using iterator_category = output_iterator_tag;
```

So `std::back_inserter` can't be used with parallel versions of `std::transform`.  The versions that support output iterators read from their source with input iterators.  Since input iterators can only be pre- and post-incremented (§23.3.5.2 Input iterators) and there is only sequential (*i.e.* non-parallel) execution, order must be preserved between them and the output iterator.

Comment: Note that these definitions from the C++ Standard does not avoid implementations to provide special versions of algorithms that are selected for additional types of iterators. For example, `std::advance` has only one definition that takes _input-iterators_, but libstdc++ provides additional versions for _bidirectional-iterators_ and _random-access-iterators_. The particular version is then [executed based on the type of iterator passed](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h#L206).

Comment: I don't think your comment is correct - `ForwardIterator`s don't mean that you have to do things in order. But you have highlighted the thing I missed - for the parallel versions they use `ForwardIterator` not `OutputIterator`.

Comment: @Timmmm I believe that if either `first1`/`last1` parameters are of _input iterator_ type, or `result` is of _output iterator_ type, the elements must be processed in order. Because the implementation does not have any other option than use `++` operation to move to next iteration. Since `std::back_inserter_iterator` is _output iterator_, then, this condition holds.

Comment: It can use `++` to move to the next iteration *without actually doing the transform* - it just needs to save copies of the iterators. The problem for `LegacyOutputIterator` is that you *can't* save copies of the iterators. For `LegacyForwardIterator` you can.

Comment: @Timmmm _It can use ++ to move to the next iteration without actually doing the transform_ – Not with _output interators_, and, `std::back_inserter_iterator` is an output iterator.

Comment: This answer could benefit from adding some words to explain what it actually means.

Comment: @Barry Added some words, any and all feed back much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing I missed is that the parallel versions take [`LegacyForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)s, not `LegacyOutputIterator`. A `LegacyForwardIterator` *can* be incremented without invalidating copies of it, so it is easy to use this to implement an out-of-order parallel `std::transform`.

I think the non-parallel versions of `std::transform` *must* be executed in-order. Either cppreference is wrong about it, or possibly the standard just leaves this requirement implicit because there is no other way to implement it. (Shotgun not wading through the standard to find out!)

Comment: The non parallel versions of transform *may* execute out-of-order if all the iterators are sufficiently strong. In the example in the question they are not, so *that specialisation* of `transform` must be in-order.

Comment: No they mayn't, because `LegacyOutputIterator` forces you to use it in-order.

Comment: It can specialise differently for `std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T>>` and `std::vector<T>::iterator`. The first must be in order. The second has no such restriction

Comment: Ah wait I see what you mean - if you happen to pass a `LegacyForwardIterator` into the non-parallel `transform`, it could have a specialisation for that which does it out of order. Good point.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the transformation **is guaranteed to be processed in-order**. `std::back_inserter_iterator` is an *output iterator* (its `iterator_category` member type is an alias for `std::output_iterator_tag`) according to [[back.insert.iterator]](http://eel.is/c++draft/back.insert.iterator).

Consequently, `std::transform` has **no other option** on how to proceed to next iteration than to call member `operator++` on the `result` parameter.

Of course, this is valid only for overloads without execution policy, where `std::back_inserter_iterator` may not be used (it's not a *forwarding iterator*).

---

BTW, I wouldn't argument with quotes from cppreference. The statements there are often imprecise or simplified. In cases as these, it's better to look at the C++ Standard. Where, regarding to `std::transform`, there is no quote about order of operations.

Comment: *"C++ Standard. Where, regarding to std::transform, there is no quote about order of operations"* Since the order is not mentioned, isn't it unspecified?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Explicitly unspecified, but imposed by the output iterator. Note that with output iterators, once you increment it, you may not dereference any previous iterator value.

Comment: @DanielLangr, what about `std::execution::par`?

Comment: @Sergei Don't understand your question. How would you define an order of operations if they can happen in parallel? If they should be ordered, there could be no parallel processing.