# SystemVerilog: From a vector of structs, get a vector that collects one of the fields for every struct

Tags: vector, struct, system-verilog

I have a vector of structs and I want to access one field of all the elements in a somewhat elegant way. I found a really similar question posted for C++ ([From a vector of structs, get a vector that collects one of the fields for every struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879969/from-a-vector-of-structs-get-a-vector-that-collects-one-of-the-fields-for-every)). My code looks somewhat similar to this (I show a very simplified version) where `example.valid` would be the vector I want to get.

```
typedef struct { 
     logic valid;
     logic [2:0] a;
} custom_t;


custom_t   example [3:0]; 
logic      aux0, aux1, aux2, aux3;
logic[1:0] mv0, mv1, mv2, mv3;

...
assign example.valid = {4{aux0}} & 4'b001<<mv0 
                     | {4{aux1}} & 4'b001<<mv1 
                     | {4{aux2}} & 4'b001<<mv2 
                     | {4{aux3}} & 4'b001<<mv3;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog does not have elegant ways of accessing individual fields of struct in an array without iterating over them. But there are elegant ways of selecting the bits of the expression on the RHS using a concatenation.

```
always_comb foreach(example[i]) example[i].valid = 
                    {  {4{aux0}} & 4'b001<<mv0 
                     | {4{aux1}} & 4'b001<<mv1 
                     | {4{aux2}} & 4'b001<<mv2 
                     | {4{aux3}} & 4'b001<<mv3 }[i];
```